# Open new Tabs on a UserControl while checking the Checkboxes on a ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

I am trying to make a program in MVVM which can read Excel files and generate the content into a Word file. Now I am stuck at making new `Tab`s on a `UserControl`, every time someone chooses to create a Word file on the checkbox:

[image: MainWindow with Checkbox]

It should generate a new tab on my second `UserControl` which I am trying to generate from my ViewModel called `HauptfensterViewModel`.

[image: Second Window where the Tabs should be generated]

The code in the view-model looks like this:

```
protected void OnWeiterExecute(object obj)
{
    OnDokumentChanged();
    new VorschauViewModel(view);
    if (Dokumenttyp[0] == true)
    {
        //TabItem auf VorschauWindow erstellen, mit jeweiligem Dokumentennamen(Angebotsvorlage)
    }
    if (Dokumenttyp[1] == true)
    {
        //TabItem auf VorschauWindow erstellen mit jeweiligem Dokumentennamen(Auditplan)
    }
    if (Dokumenttyp[2] == true)
    {
        //TabItem auf VorschauWindow erstellen mit jeweiligem Dokumentennamen(Checkliste)
    }
    if (Dokumenttyp[3] == true)
    {
        //TabItem auf VorschauWindow erstellen mit jeweiligem Dokumentennamen(Dokumentationsvorlage)
    }               
}
```

I appreciate your help and I will try to answer all questions if there is something not understandable.

Comment: As there are four `CheckBoxes`, so it will add four `TabItems` at most?

Comment: Are the two `USerControls` in the same `Window`?

Comment: Actually, you're totally missing the MVVM concept. A view-model should not create any `TabItem`s (because they're view elements, and a view-model should not bother about any views). This line confirms that fact once again: `new VorschauViewModel(view);` - you're passing a view to a view-model, this is (generally) not MVVM-ish.

Comment: @Iron yes it should generate only 4 TabItems

Comment: @dymanoid well, ok i didnt know that, thank you.So should i generate them on my UserControl.cs then?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. You define them in XAML as `DataTemplate`s, or `ControlTemplate`s, or whatever you need, and then you create data bindings for the corresponding view-model properties to let WPF do the job for you. Please read more about MVVM + WPF, these are the basics.

Comment: one approach would be to enable/disable tabs instead of creating and deleting tabs in the control. 2 advantages, one is that it is easy to implement in MVVM and second is that it is faster then creating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you can try something code like following example, which is not the best solution, but it can help you to understand more about the `MVVM`.

ViewModel:

```
public class HauptfensterViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static HauptfensterViewModel Instance { get; } = new HauptfensterViewModel();

    private HauptfensterViewModel()
    {
    }

    private bool _property1;
    private bool _property2;
    private bool _property3;
    private bool _property4;

    public bool Property1
    {
        get { return _property1; }
        set
        {
            _property1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool Property2
    {
        get { return _property2; }
        set
        {
            _property2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool Property3
    {
        get { return _property3; }
        set
        {
            _property3 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool Property4
    {
        get { return _property4; }
        set
        {
            _property4 = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

UserControl1:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Property1}"/>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Property2}"/>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Property3}"/>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Property4}"/>
```

UserControl2:

```
<TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="ToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabItem Header="1" Visibility="{Binding Property1,Converter={StaticResource ToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    <TabItem Header="2" Visibility="{Binding Property2,Converter={StaticResource ToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    <TabItem Header="3" Visibility="{Binding Property3,Converter={StaticResource ToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    <TabItem Header="4" Visibility="{Binding Property4,Converter={StaticResource ToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</TabControl>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        DataContext = HauptfensterViewModel.Instance;
    }
}
public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl2()
    {
        DataContext = HauptfensterViewModel.Instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution has three bad design decisions: 1) a `static` property providing a "stateful" object; 2) one view-model for two different views; and 3) wiring a view to a view-model in the view's constructor via a singleton. The code review team would reject such a commit.

Comment: Yes, it not a good solution, just to help a novice to understand more about the `MVVM`.